I will let you know when I am ready - meaning?
sentences like,

It teaches you what you shouldn't be doing in the real world.
I will let you know when I am ready.

In everyday communication, someone might say "I'll let you know when I'm ready."  I understand this to mean the speaker will inform me at the time they are prepared.  However, is there an alternative interpretation, something closer to "you will know the time when I am ready"?
I'm curious if the second interpretation is a common way to understand this phrase, or if the first interpretation ("informing at the time") is the only intended meaning.

'Let someone know something' is a phrasal verb meaning 'tell or inform someone about something'. That is its only meaning.

What are you asking about the first case? In the second case it might not be soon. They may not even be in a position to get ready, but "I will let you know" means they will inform you when they are. If your supposition were correct, they would have said "You will know when I am ready."

@WeatherVane
Relative Clauses: The phrase "when I'm ready" functions as a relative clause. It modifies the noun phrase "the time" (even though it's not explicitly stated). Relative pronouns (like "who," "which," "that," or "when" in this case) connect the relative clause to the main clause and specify what information applies to the main clause noun.
Function of "When": In this context, "when" refers to the point in time, not the state of being ready itself. It tells us when the informing will happen, not that the state of readiness will become somehow perceptible.

The second sentence is ambiguous. For example a) when I have got ready to leave (for an event say), or b) when I am ready to tell you (about something else).
